# How do I center this Add to Cart button on WooCommerce Product Page?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've had to throw up this WooCommerce store today, but I've had trouble centering the "Add to Cart" button. I've tried several code snippets, but honestly I'm just having trouble with identifying which CSS class to call for this button. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Here's a test product page to look at - https://magzsports.com/product/redford-logo-yellow-shirt/

Using WordPress with Flatsome theme from Evanto. WooCommerce is backend store.

Answer (score 0):

¿is the "add to cart button" custom? There is a lot of code that I don't know what is doing there (a stripe button disabled? a form?)
After cleaning the code, I just added a class to each element to see if something was causing conflict (cart now is called carrito, goback button now is just "goback", input button is "inputo") and just added this code:

```
.carrito {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is how it looks for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code is not custom. It's from the WooCommerce plugin. I'd like to clean it up, but I don't necessarily know what's going on with